# Crystal Reports click events

Tags: crystal-reports

Here is my scenario . I have a crystal reports viewer that contains,for example, two columns : a bill number and the corresponding client. To make things easier for the user , I want to allow the user to click/double-click on any row under the bill number column and take him/her directly to a windows form where he/she can edit the bill with that specific number .
Is that possible ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible..

1.ADD a ole object just adjacent to the (field)bill number..

2.Right-click the graphic and select Format Graphic.

3.On the Hyperlink tab..

```
In the Hyperlink Type area, select the A Website on the Internet radio button.
In the Hyperlink Information area, in the Website Address field, enter the following string:
```

http://$b1$/link?table=OITM&key=I001

4.Click the Formula button to the right of the Website Address field. The Formula Workshop –
Format Formula Editor – Hyperlink Text window opens.

5.In the work area, enter the following string as shown below:
'http://$b1$/link?table=OITM&key='+{DOC1.ItemCode}

6.In the toolbar, choose the Save and Close button.

7.In the Format Editor window, choose the OK button.

Now on wards when you view report in report viewer.if you click on the ole object it will redirect you to the window where the end user can update the value..

Thanks

Ankur

Comment: I want to point out that the application is a desktop based windows forms application and not a website

Comment: The example i provided  is for sap business one(desktop application) but not sure does other desktop application have similar functionality..

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this in crystal Report.

CrystalReportViewer API's Dose not expose any events to do that.